# Why val() function doesn't work with later rendered html?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, delegates

so I have an add minus button rendered with javascript because I needed data from a database and if I don't render it with javascript it will work but it doesn't work.

HTML:

```html
<div id="cart">
  <div class="row">

  </div>  
</div>
```

JS (rendering):

```js
var output = [];
var food_template = [];
//res is the data got from database
for(var f in res) {
  id = res[f]["id"];
  name = res[f]["name"];
  description = res[f]["description"];
  price = res[f]["price"];
  food_template = [
    '<div class="col-6">',
    '    <div class="single_food_item media">',
    '        <div class="media-body", style="margin-right:10px; margin-top: 20px; height: 200px">',
    `            <h3>${name}</h3>`,
    `            <p>${description}</p>`,
    `            <h5>$${price}</h5>`,
    //add minus button starts
    '            <div class="input-group" style="width:50%">',
    '                <span class="input-group-btn">',
    '                    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-minus" type="button">-</button>',
    '                </span>',
    '                <input type="text" class="form-control no-padding add-color text-center height-25" maxlength="3" value="0">',
    '                <span class="input-group-btn">',
    '                    <button class="btn btn-success btn-plus" type="button">+</button>',
    '                </span>',
    '            </div>',
    //add minus button ends
    '        </div>',
    '    </div>',
    '</div>'
  ];
  output.push(food_template.join("\n"));
}
("#cart .row").html(output.join("\n"));
```

JS (add minus button):

```js
$('#cart .row').delegate('.btn-minus', 'click', function(){
  $(this).parent().siblings('input').val(parseInt($(this).parent().siblings('input').val()) - 1);
});

$('#cart .row').delegate('.btn-minus', 'click', function(){
  $(this).parent().siblings('input').val(parseInt($(this).parent().siblings('input').val()) + 1)
});
```

(all functions are called)

What I test made me think that the problem is probably the val() function isn't changing the value of the input HTML since if I use console.log to show it it works but it doesn't update on the web

Comment: HI, both event handler are for `btn-minus` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have both the plus and the minus event handlers attached to the minus button, so when you click it, the plus handler increments the value and the minus handler decrements it, therefore you see no change regarding the value of the input